# how to get top 10 average in mysql with two columns average

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table from that I want to get top 10 avg points group by playerID and average will get by dividing two columns .

I am using below query but getting no results .

```
SELECT PlayerID
     , GamesPlayed
     , TeamID
     , AVG(Points/GamesPlayed AS avg_points) 
  FROM playerseasons 
 WHERE seasonID = '1008' 
   AND TeamID IN 
(2,5,42,4,6,8,9,10,13,12,11,38,15) 
 GROUP 
    BY PlayerID 
 ORDER 
    BY avg_points DESC 
 LIMIT 10
```

this is only getting average by points, I need it like below image, divide the points by game played that will be average

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did this with below query

```
SELECT 
    PlayerID,
    GamesPlayed,
    TeamID,
    Points / GamesPlayed AS avg_points
FROM
    playerseasons
WHERE
    seasonID = '1008'
        AND TeamID IN (2 , 5, 42,  4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 12, 11, 38, 15)
GROUP BY PlayerID
ORDER BY avg_points DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hey your question is bit unclear, it's hard to understand you, as the strawberry pointed it ,please edit and add more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PlayerID, GamesPlayed, TeamID, avg(Points/GamesPlayed) AS avg_points FROM playerseasons WHERE seasonID='1008' AND TeamID IN (2,5,42,4,6,8,9,10,13,12,11,38,15) GROUP BY PlayerID,GamesPlayed, TeamID
ORDER BY avg_points DESC LIMIT 10
```

I haven't tested it, try if it works you were missing some columns in group by.